# Eslint rule to ban some import paths

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I have following structure.

```
.
└── src
    └── pages
        └── Chat
            ├── Chat.tsx
            ├── index.ts
            └── components
                ├── index.ts
                └── AppsBar
                    ├── AppsBar.tsx
                    ├── AppTile.ts
                    └── index.ts
```

From `Chat.tsx` I want to import `AppsBar` component (each has named exports, and index with export all).

Do it by hand it would look that: `import { AppsBar } from './components';`. But VSC or WebStorm creates automatic path: `import { AppsBar } from '~/pages/Chat/components/AppsBar';` (I have aliases).

**Question**:
Is there any ESLint rule to force using `/.` notation when I want access to file from the same level?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"` in vscodes user settings or otherwise set `baseUrl` in your tsconfig.json (see [module-resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping))